# Deleting all text after a specific string for multiple text files in a directory

Tags: text-processing, sed, json

I have roughly 25,000 JSON files that I need to validate and check and I have noticed that some of the files have duplicated themselves causing errors when converting the JSON into a CSV using Excel.

I am trying to delete all string after `"version":"0.2.3"}` as this indicates the end of the JSON before repeating itself `"version": "0.2.3"}{"analysis": {` so I need to keep `"version": "0.2.3"}` and remove `{"analysis": {` and everything that follows it and apply these changes to all 25,000 files. I have seen people using grep and sed but can't seem to get them working myself.

Would appreciate if anyone can help as manually deleting the text isn't advisable so I am hoping for a one liner in bash or something!

Below is what I need to fix (trimmed down version of one of the files) and below that is the desired output. As you can see for whatever reason the JSON data duplicated itself maybe during the API usage.

Problematic Input (trimmed `json`):

```json
{"analysis":{"score":3},"sample":{"completed":"2022-01-27T21:22:21Z","created":"2022-01-27T21:17:57Z","id":"220127-z5h84saffl","md5":"7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d","score":3,"sha1":"58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601","sha256":"23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a"},"version":"0.2.3"}{"analysis":{"score":3},"sample":{"completed":"2022-01-27T21:22:21Z","created":"2022-01-27T21:17:57Z","id":"220127-z5h84saffl","md5":"7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d","score":3,"sha1":"58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601","sha256":"23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a"},"version":"0.2.3"}
```

Desired Output:

```json
{"analysis":{"score":3},"sample":{"completed":"2022-01-27T21:22:21Z","created":"2022-01-27T21:17:57Z","id":"220127-z5h84saffl","md5":"7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d","score":3,"sha1":"58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601","sha256":"23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a"},"version":"0.2.3"}
```

Comment: It seems like the data that you're dealing with is JSON. Specific utilities are available for working with JSON data that would make this operation trivial. Still, to be able to suggest anything that would be useful to you, you would first have to show a complete example of one of the JSON documents.  Also, converting JSON into CSV is easily done with command-line tools.

Comment: If you have clarifications to your question, please edit the text of the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have added two samples which I hope can provide some additional context! I am looking for a way to remove everything after the first instance of "version":"0.2.3"}

Answer (score 5):

Using `jq` (available for most Unix-like systems), you could extract the first JSON object from a file and discard the rest using

```bash
jq -n 'input' file >newfile
```

This produces "pretty-printed" JSON.  Use the `-c` option to get "compact" output (a single line with minimal whitespace).  The output is written to `newfile`.

The `jq` instruction `input` produces the next available JSON object.  We turn off the default reading of the data using `-n` (`--null-input`) and use `input` to only process the very first object in the input file.

For the given data in the question, this produces

```json
{
  "analysis": {
    "score": 3
  },
  "sample": {
    "completed": "2022-01-27T21:22:21Z",
    "created": "2022-01-27T21:17:57Z",
    "id": "220127-z5h84saffl",
    "md5": "7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d",
    "score": 3,
    "sha1": "58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601",
    "sha256": "23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a"
  },
  "version": "0.2.3"
}
```

Then simple overwrite the original file with the result.  The complete processing of a single file could possibly look like

```bash
jq -n 'input' file >newfile &&
mv newfile file
```

Assuming your files are located in the current directory and match some pattern `*.json`, then you may process all files in a simple shell loop like this:

```bash
for name in *.json; do
    cp -- "$name" "$name.orig" &&
    jq -n 'input' <"$name.orig" >"$name"
done
```

This does things a bit differently from what I just showed, leaving the original contents in files with a `.orig` filename suffix and ensuring that the original file's metadata (permissions etc.) are not altered.  Once you have made sure this does the correct thing, you may delete the files with the `.orig` filename suffix.

Always test things like this on data that is properly backed up.

---

You also mentioned converting these files into CSV but said nothing else about what you needed regarding this.  Assuming you might want the `sample` data as CSV, with the keys as headers:

```bash
jq -n -r 'input | .sample | keys, [.[]] | @csv' file
```

The `-r` option (`--raw-output`) is needed to give you decoded data, not JSON strings.

For the given document, this would give you

```
"completed","created","id","md5","score","sha1","sha256"
"2022-01-27T21:22:21Z","2022-01-27T21:17:57Z","220127-z5h84saffl","7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d",3,"58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601","23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a"
```

Comment: This worked brilliant for a single file! I also appreciate the help with converting it to a CSV file. do you have any advice for doing this to 28,678 files in a directory? I will try turning it into a loop and see where it gets me

Comment: @Jarvis4444 See added bit before the divider.

Comment: @Jarvis4444 For more precise help with converting into CSV, I would suggest asking a separate question about it. We tend to want single-issue questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Sample Input (erroneous JSON):

```bash
~$ cat file.json
{"analysis":{"score":3},"sample":{"completed":"2022-01-27T21:22:21Z","created":"2022-01-27T21:17:57Z","id":"220127-z5h84saffl","md5":"7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d","score":3,"sha1":"58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601","sha256":"23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a"},"version":"0.2.3"}{"analysis":{"score":3},"sample":{"completed":"2022-01-27T21:22:21Z","created":"2022-01-27T21:17:57Z","id":"220127-z5h84saffl","md5":"7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d","score":3,"sha1":"58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601","sha256":"23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a"},"version":"0.2.3"}
```

Sample Output (Raku's hash format):

```perl
~$ cat file.json | raku -MJSON::Stream -e 'my @a;  \
   react whenever json-stream($*IN.Supply, [q[$], *][0],) {@a.push($_.values)};  \
   "\n".print; .say for @a.[0].hash;'

sample => {completed => 2022-01-27T21:22:21Z, created => 2022-01-27T21:17:57Z, id => 220127-z5h84saffl, md5 => 7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d, score => 3, sha1 => 58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601, sha256 => 23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a}
version => 0.2.3
analysis => {score => 3}
```

Above, incomplete JSON can be read-in using Raku's `JSON::Stream` module, which--because it's a JSON stream parser (parsing before the EOF is reached)--doesn't validate the JSON. That's fortunate in this case. The erroneous second element gets dropped from the array using the `@a.[0].hash` call (`@a.head.hash` also works).

---

Final Output in `JSON` format is accomplished using the `to-json()` command from Raku's `JSON::Tiny` module. Putting it all together, this is what we do:

Final JSON Output (using only Raku modules):

```json
~$ cat Jarvis4444.json | raku -MJSON::Stream -MJSON::Tiny -e 'my @a;  \
   react whenever json-stream($*IN.Supply, [q[$], *][0],) {@a.push($_.values)};  \
   "\n".print; to-json(@a.[0].hash).put;'

{ "version" : "0.2.3", "sample" : { "score" : 3, "created" : "2022-01-27T21:17:57Z", "sha1" : "58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601", "id" : "220127-z5h84saffl", "sha256" : "23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a", "md5" : "7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d", "completed" : "2022-01-27T21:22:21Z" }, "analysis" : { "score" : 3 } }
```

---

For comparison with other answers, the JSON output immediately above can be `|` piped through `jq`:

```json
{
  "sample": {
    "completed": "2022-01-27T21:22:21Z",
    "score": 3,
    "sha1": "58a8689ee76a46559ea56a52d20425f44c8ff601",
    "md5": "7871a75734af389b787bad57a3ea087d",
    "id": "220127-z5h84saffl",
    "sha256": "23c5dee027c7969aabb5828641c55a005f30fb166a5006dbe3a817f56ca0e32a",
    "created": "2022-01-27T21:17:57Z"
  },
  "version": "0.2.3",
  "analysis": {
    "score": 3
  }
}
```

[Processing multiple files:  Certainly the answer by @Kusalananda provides ample guidance on writing a shell loop to process multiple files, correcting/saving each one].

https://github.com/moritz/json
https://github.com/FCO/JSON-Stream
https://raku.org